# Selenium on Mac - how to use CONTROL instead of COMMAND in tests

Tags: macos, selenium, google-chrome, command, controls

we are using the function `sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"))` in our Selenium tests. Well, some developers have switched to macbooks on which this does not work, becouse they are using COMMAND instead of CONTROL (macbooks have a different keyboard layout). So we are trying to come up with a solution to somehow globally replace CONTROL with COMMAND in the tests, but it would be good to make this change locally for mac using developers, as other developers still use windows.

Does anyone know of a solution? Whether to change it somehow globally in the idea or directly in the macbook? I would like to avoid the replaceall function.

Thanks

So far I just tried replacing control with command and it worked.

Comment: I'd suggesting checking the current operating system and use the corresponding key.

I'll assume that this is about java's selenium, you can use `System.getProperty("os.name")` to get the OS name. MacOS is named darwin

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check the operating system then use the keys necessary ( Darwin is for MAC):

```
import platform

os = platform.system()

if os == 'Darwin':

    selector.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'a')

else:

    selector.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
```